# I entered with one passport but am trying to leave with another

Tags: visas, usa, passports

I entered US with a temporary Brazilian passport, I am not Brazilian, and now it is canceled. Can I leave US with a passport from Venezuela? My visa has the Brazilian passport number, but if the passport is not valid any more is my visa also not valid?

Comment: Why was your Brazilian passport cancelled? Did it just expire, or was it fraudulent or was there some other problem with it?

Comment: How did you you obtain a Brazilian passport without being Brazilian? That seems like a problem.

Comment: I was asking for the brazilian citizenship, so they gave me temporary documents for two years, but I lost the date I was supose to ask for the definitive documents and to make the citizenship official. So I lost everything and will have to start all over again. But I will have to leave the country with my venezuelan passport.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I leave US with a passport from Venezuela?

The U.S. has no exit checks. So pretty much anyone can leave the U.S. fine as long as they can enter the destination country.

> My visa has the Brazilian passport number, but if the passport is not
>   valid any more is my visa also not valid?

The visa would be valid if used with another Brazilian passport. But since you do not have a Brazilian passport, no, the visa is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will just leave the country and try for new documents in Brazil, and then I will ask another visa.

Comment: @RenataNascimento: If you can get a Brazilian passport, then you can still use your existing visa (if it is not expired) and not need to get a new visa.

Answer (score 1):

A visa is linked to a passport number. If you renew a passport and the visa associated with it is still valid you shouldn't move the visa in the new passport but leave it in the old  one and present both when passing a border (if that visa is requested at that border).

In your case as the passports are from different countries this visa shouldn't be valid anymore unless maybe you'd renew your Brazilian passport.

As @user102008 said, there is no need for a visa to leave US. In US, Canada and many other countries there are no exit checks.

Comment: You are right @user102008 already said so _"The visa would be valid if used with another Brazilian passport. But since you do not have a Brazilian passport, no, the visa is not valid."_ (Updated my answer to avoid confusion)

Comment: @pnuts, wasn't this answer first?

Comment: @pnuts, if both had the same time stamp, then ok. But to come along an hour later with a redundant answer...  I see your point.

Comment: @svassr, try to be more FGITW, because your answer looks like you copied an earlier one.

Comment: Got it.  Probably a hat thing.  He may be going for the 'fear and loathing' hat or something like that. I got that hat by accident.]

Comment: :) I was not looking for a particular hat. I just wanted add details about the possibility to pass a border with a renewed passeport and an old visa, which is maybe what Renata will need to do at some point. Otherwise @user102008 's answer was totally correct and I already upvoted it myself.